# matplotlib error : loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

This is my dataSeries :
df =

```
        count
17    83396.142857
18    35970.000000
19    54082.428571
20    21759.714286
21    16899.571429
22    19870.571429
23    32491.285714
24    40425.285714
25    30780.285714
26    11923.428571
27    13698.571429
28    28028.000000
29    52575.000000
```

First converted it to int to avoid any issues:

```
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
```

I am trying to plot the data using :

```py
    _, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    df.plot.pie(ax = ax[1], y = df['count'])
    plt.show()
```

but it keeps throwing the exception error:

```
Type:
  TypeError
Message:
  loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable rint method
Stacktrace:
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 61, in _draw
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1863, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2747, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1164, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1022, in _update_ticks
    major_labels = self.major.formatter.format_ticks(major_locs)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 249, in format_ticks
    self.set_locs(values)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 782, in set_locs
    self._set_format()
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 884, in _set_format
    if np.abs(locs - np.round(locs, decimals=sigfigs)).max() < thresh:
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in round_
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3739, in round_
    return around(a, decimals=decimals, out=out)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in around
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 3314, in around
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 66, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/eyshikaagarwal/.virtualenvs/env-hss-ml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 43, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
[0m
```

Any suggestions .. what is wrong here ?
I already spent hours to understand and fix it but no luck yet.
Any help would be great.

**Update :**

Thank you @ehsan for the answer it worked for the pie chart , but I still get the same error when i do simple line plot using:

```py
plot_kwargs = {'xticks': df.index,
               'grid': True,
                'color': 'Red',
               'title' : "Average "}

df.plot(ylabel = 'Average No. of tracks ', **plot_kwargs)
```

Its the exact same error I am getting with this code and I dont understand why . i even used `y='count'` here too , just to see if anything changes but its the same error.
Any insights will be helpful
Thank You!

Comment: one question, why ``df.plot.pie(ax = ax[1], y = df['count'])`` instead of directly just ``df.plot.pie(y='count')``?
Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html

Comment: I am using subplots thats why i used ax[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want this:

```
_, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
df.plot.pie(ax = ax[1], y = 'count')
plt.show()
```

The mistake is you use `y=df['count']` instead of simply `y='count'`. You are using pandas plotting and no need to send column values, only column name. Also, you do not need to convert the dtype to `int`, unless you want to do it.

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It did work on using `y='count'` for pie chart , but when i am doing it for simple line plot for same dataframe, it again gives same error. and i dont understand why. This time I tried with/without converting to int as well and with/without `y='count'`. You can check the question for the updated code regarding the same under updates. Thank You!

Comment: @Eyshika You are welcome. Your update would be a different question. For starters, you have not defined the type of plot you want in the code and `x` is unknown. Also, your sample data frame does not have a `'Average No. of tracks '` column. I would suggest checking the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html on how to use plot in pandas. You could also provide a minimal example and specify what you want to plot so we can help better. And if the answer resolves the question you ask, always accepting answer is good to close the question. Thank you.

Comment: `'Average Number of tracks'` is the label i.e. Name to use for the ylabel on y-axis not the data which is mentioned as y . Also the same code works for other dataframes am using, which looks exctly same just the numbers are different, but not for this one. Also if we dont mention `kind`, it considers it as line plot. and as i said it does draw line plot using same code for other dataframes in same format, but not this one. i dont know why